# How to change class where children and grandchildren are same class JQUERY

Tags: jquery, css

I am developing one menu and I want to changed the icon when somebody click it. I have changed the icon but all children that they have change the icon too, due to they share same class. The structure is similar to:

[image]

And when click it we can see.
[image]

Menu selected has changed but its children too. The problem is that icon change because the class name and this class name are the same in children and grandchildren.

Html:

```
<li id="formularioMenu:j_id244" role="menuitem" class="active-menu-parent">
    <a href="#" class="menulink ripplelink active-menu active-menu-restore">
        <i class="icon-null"></i>
        <i class="icon-folder-empty"></i> 
        Foo2
        <i class="icon-add Fright Fs16"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="menu-level-1 active-menu active-menu-restore" role="menu">
        <li id="formularioMenu:j_id245" role="menuitem">
            <a class="menulink ripplelink" href="http://localhost:8080/foo21.xhtml">
            <i class="icon-null"></i>
            <i class="icon-doc-text-1"></i>
            Foo2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li id="formularioMenu:j_id246" role="menuitem">
            <a class="menulink ripplelink" href="http://localhost:8080/foo22.xhtml">
            <i class="icon-null"></i>
            <i class="icon-doc-text-1"></i>
            Foo2.2</a>
        </li>
        <li id="formularioMenu:j_id247" role="menuitem">
            <a class="menulink ripplelink" href="http://localhost:8080/foo23.xhtml">
            <i class="icon-null"></i>
            <i class="icon-doc-text-1"></i>
            Foo2.3</a>
        </li>
        <li id="formularioMenu:j_id248" role="menuitem">
            <a class="menulink ripplelink" href="http://localhost:8080/foo24.xhtml">
            <i class="icon-null"></i>
            <i class="icon-doc-text-1"></i>
            Foo2.4</a>
            <i class="icon-add Fright Fs16"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="menu-level-2" role="menu">
            ...
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="formularioMenu:j_id249" role="menuitem">
            <a class="menulink ripplelink" href="http://localhost:8080/foo25.xhtml">
            <i class="icon-null"></i>
            <i class="icon-doc-text-1"></i>
            Foo2.5</a>
            <i class="icon-add Fright Fs16"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="menu-level-2" role="menu">
            ...
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="formularioMenu:j_id250" role="menuitem">
            <a href="#" class="menulink ripplelink">
            <i class="icon-null"></i>
            <i class="icon-folder-empty"></i> 
            Foo2.6          
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</li>
```

With this **class="icon-add Fright Fs16"**    I change the icon image. I must alternate between icon-add and icon-minus class.

Part of my JQuery code, the "logo" variable does the action to change name class. A part to change from Minus to Add and another part to reverse :

```
bindEvents: function() {
    var $this = this;
    
    if(this.mobile) {
        this.menuWrapper.css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    }
    else {
        this.menuWrapper.perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true});
    }

    this.menulinks.on('click',function(e) {
        var menuitemLink = $(this),
        menuitem = menuitemLink.parent();

        if(menuitem.hasClass('active-menu-parent')) {
            var logo = menuitem.find('i.icon-minus');
            
            if(logo.hasClass('icon-minus')){                    
                logo.removeClass('icon-minus');
                logo.addClass('icon-add');
            }
            
            menuitem.removeClass('active-menu-parent');
            menuitemLink.removeClass('active-menu active-menu-restore').next('ul').removeClass('active-menu active-menu-restore');
            $this.removeMenuitem(menuitem.attr('id'));
        }
        else {
            var activeSibling = menuitem.siblings('.active-menu-parent');
            if(activeSibling.length) {
                activeSibling.removeClass('active-menu-parent');
                $this.removeMenuitem(activeSibling.attr('id'));

                activeSibling.find('ul.active-menu,a.active-menu').removeClass('active-menu active-menu-restore');
                activeSibling.find('li.active-menu-parent').each(function() {
                    var menuitem = $(this);
                    menuitem.removeClass('active-menu-parent');
                    $this.removeMenuitem(menuitem.attr('id'));
                });
            }
            
            var logo = menuitem.find('i.icon-add');
            
            if(logo.hasClass('icon-add')){                  
                logo.removeClass('icon-add');
                logo.addClass('icon-minus');
            }

            menuitem.addClass('active-menu-parent');
            menuitemLink.addClass('active-menu').next('ul').addClass('active-menu');
            $this.addMenuitem(menuitem.attr('id'));
        }

        if(menuitemLink.next().is('ul')) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            $this.menuWrapper.removeClass('showmenu');
            $this.mobileMenuButton.removeClass('MenuClose');
        }

        $this.saveMenuState();
        
        if(!$this.mobile) {
            $this.menuWrapper.perfectScrollbar("update");
        }
    });
```

When function find its, gets alls children and grandchildren with icon-add class. So how can I change only the menu selected?

Regards.

Comment: A lot of times people will use a class or something to identify which items are selected. For example, `.is-selected { //selected css }`

Comment: Like this for example.. https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ `.ui-state-active`

Comment: This is a whole lot of code for a simple feature, you've gotten into a if/else hell that's hard to read and debug. Have you considered starting fresh and keeping it simple? Like Kris said, I think the style should be handled with a class.

Comment: @veksen This is not my code, is the theme code of the template that I am using.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck I have tried do this but not work. var enlace = menuitem.find('menulink.ripplelink.active-menu');

Answer (score 0):

Finally I gets my goals. How I can't find the specific element, I decided iterate all children level and when I gets the element that I want, I remove old class and insert new class. Copy the code, my modification is between //jmf comments. One part to change + to - and another part to change - to +.

```
bindEvents: function() {
    var $this = this;

    if(this.mobile) {
        this.menuWrapper.css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    }
    else {
        this.menuWrapper.perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true});
    }

    this.menulinks.on('click',function(e) {
        var menuitemLink = $(this),
        menuitem = menuitemLink.parent();

        if(menuitem.hasClass('active-menu-parent')) {
            //jmf
            var enlace = menuitem.children();

            if(enlace.length){
                var vinculo = enlace.first();

                if(vinculo.length){
                    var lineasVinculo = vinculo.children();

                    if(lineasVinculo.length){
                        var logo = lineasVinculo.last();

                        if(logo.length){
                            if(logo.hasClass('icon-minus')){
                                logo.removeClass('icon-minus');
                                logo.addClass('icon-add');                                  
                            }                                                               
                        }                           
                    }                       
                }
            }
            //fin jmf

            menuitem.removeClass('active-menu-parent');
            menuitemLink.removeClass('active-menu active-menu-restore').next('ul').removeClass('active-menu active-menu-restore');
            $this.removeMenuitem(menuitem.attr('id'));
        }
        else {
            var activeSibling = menuitem.siblings('.active-menu-parent');
            if(activeSibling.length) {
                activeSibling.removeClass('active-menu-parent');
                $this.removeMenuitem(activeSibling.attr('id'));

                activeSibling.find('ul.active-menu,a.active-menu').removeClass('active-menu active-menu-restore');
                activeSibling.find('li.active-menu-parent').each(function() {
                    var menuitem = $(this);
                    menuitem.removeClass('active-menu-parent');
                    $this.removeMenuitem(menuitem.attr('id'));
                });
            }               

            //jmf
            var enlace = menuitem.children();

            if(enlace.length){
                var vinculo = enlace.first();

                if(vinculo.length){
                    var lineasVinculo = vinculo.children();

                    if(lineasVinculo.length){
                        var logo = lineasVinculo.last();

                        if(logo.length){
                            if(logo.hasClass('icon-add')){
                                logo.removeClass('icon-add');
                                logo.addClass('icon-minus');                                    
                            }                                                               
                        }                           
                    }                       
                }
            }    
            //fin jmf

            menuitem.addClass('active-menu-parent');
            menuitemLink.addClass('active-menu').next('ul').addClass('active-menu');
            $this.addMenuitem(menuitem.attr('id'));
        }

        if(menuitemLink.next().is('ul')) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            $this.menuWrapper.removeClass('showmenu');
            $this.mobileMenuButton.removeClass('MenuClose');
        }

        $this.saveMenuState();

        if(!$this.mobile) {
            $this.menuWrapper.perfectScrollbar("update");
        }
    });
```